# Power Query for Excel, Getting Posts from a Group Returns Empty When It Shouldn't?

Tags: excel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, powerquery

I am using Power Query on Excel to grab relevant data from a facebook group that I am the admin of. I can pull off some information such as the members in the group, but when I try to pull of posts it states that the table is empty.

It has a different reaction from when I try and call an object that doesn't exist ("post" for example says it is an unknown path), and as stated "members" brings back a list of the members in the group. I don't understand why it then accepts the request to get the "posts" and returns an empty set of data when there are plenty of posts in it.

Can anyone highlight why this might be the case? I'm completely stumped and need a solution! I have even set the group as public to try and eliminate any potential blocks but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that you are running into this issue. The permissions required to read the feed from a (public/private)group is not approved for Power Query application. So, there isn't a way to read the posts for now.